# JavaFX Image not shown

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I've declared 4 ImageView variables as global and then instantiated them in a method `loadImgs()`

```
    private ImageView image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4 ;

    private void loadImgs()
    {
        image_1 = new ImageView(new Image("img1.jpg")) ;
        image_1.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_1.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_1.setCache(true) ;

        image_2 = new ImageView(new Image("img2.jpg")) ;
        image_2.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_2.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_2.setCache(true) ;

        image_3 = new ImageView(new Image("img3.jpg")) ;
        image_3.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_3.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_3.setCache(true) ;

        image_4 = new ImageView(new Image("img4.jpg")) ;
        image_4.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_4.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_4.setCache(true) ;

        image_4 = new ImageView(new Image("img4.jpg")) ;
        image_4.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_4.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_4.setCache(true) ;
    }
```

All the images are in the same folder as is the source code.

The `loadImgs()` method is called at the very beginning. Later on I add the instantiated `ImageView`s into Layouts in other methods which are added to new `Scene`s like shown below.

```
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane() ;
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(image_4, b_pane) ;

        scene_4 = new Scene(stackPane, sceneWidth, sceneHeight) ;

        window.setScene(scene_4) ;
```

There are around 4 `Scene`s each with its respective `ImageView`. However, only the first 2(i.e., image_1 and image_2) are shown and the other two are not.

I'm not quite sure what's wrong. How do I solve this and what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have two instances of image_4, so you either have 5 images or one instance that's not required. Also, you create a StackPane, which adds its children one on top of another, with its z-order defined by the order of the children's list. I don't know what b_pane is, but I think that you have images 1-4 in the b_pane and one img_4 that you add separately.

How to solve this ?

You might want to create a regular Pane instead of a StackPane, or a GridPane or whatever. I'd recommend going with a regular Pane but you can choose another one according to your needs.

Also, you must add every single child to the parent in order to have them all on the Pane.

Lastly, when you declare image_4, it doesn't really change anything that you declare it again, it's ugly, but it's fine.

Here is what I would go with for the images :

```java
    private void loadImgs()
    {
        image_1 = new ImageView(new Image("img1.jpg")) ;
        image_1.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_1.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_1.setCache(true) ;

        image_2 = new ImageView(new Image("img2.jpg")) ;
        image_2.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_2.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_2.setCache(true) ;

        image_3 = new ImageView(new Image("img3.jpg")) ;
        image_3.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_3.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_3.setCache(true) ;

        image_4 = new ImageView(new Image("img4.jpg")) ;
        image_4.setFitWidth(sceneWidth) ;
        image_4.setFitHeight(sceneHeight) ;
        image_4.setCache(true) ;
    }
}
```

And this is what I would go with in your main method or whatever you're putting the last bit of code in :

```java
        Pane pane = new Pane() ;
        pane.getChildren().addAll(image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, b_pane) ;
        // Add the b_pane only if necessary. Don't add it if it contains image_1/2/3/4

        Scene scene_4 = new Scene(pane, sceneWidth, sceneHeight) ;

        window.setScene(scene_4) ;
```

Feel free to ask any question if you have got some, I'd be glad to help you out.